# Reading a JSON response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm making an ajax post request to a super simple python function that takes a student's name and spits out a url that corresponds to it. Currently, the Python function passes this back in json and looks like so when `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` is called:

`{"readyState":4,"responseText”:”\ {\”studentURL\”: \”https://prepacademy.jackjohnson.com\”} ”,”responseJSON”: {“studentURL”:”https://prepacademy.jackjohnson.com”},”status":200,"statusText":"OK"}`

I was wondering how do I take this larger chunk of information and filter it so that I would only get the `https://prepacademy.jackjohnson.com` part?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using fancy quotes while developing almost anything.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. It should contain straight quotes, not curly quotes. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: It would be MUCH simpler for us to help you if you just posted response instead of stringifying it for us

Comment: @Barmar thats the `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` copied word for word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response` is a JavaScript Object of which you can access the properties using either Dot-notation or bracket-notation, like so:

```js
let response = {
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "\ {\"studentURL\": \"https://prepacademy.jackjohnson.com\"} ",
  "responseJSON": {
    "studentURL": "https://prepacademy.jackjohnson.com"
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK"
};

// dot-notation
console.log(response.responseJSON.studentURL)

// bracket-notation (allows for computed paths)
console.log(response["responseJSON"]["studentURL"])
```

Comment: so if I wanted to use the url thats passed, could I just call it like this: `var studentURL = response.responseText.studentURL` ?

Comment: No, not `.responseText`, but `.responseJSON`. You could use `.responseText` but you would have to JSON.parse it at first ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`response.responseJSON.studentURL`